# Translate the continuous fraction $[2;2^{1!}, 2^{2!}, 2^{3!}, \cdots]$ to a sum in order to prove that it's transcendental

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, liouville-numbers

Translate the continuous fraction $[2;2^{1!}, 2^{2!}, 2^{3!}, \cdots]$ to a sum in order to prove that it's transcendental

The task is to prove that the number $[2;2^{1!}, 2^{2!}, 2^{3!}, \cdots]$ is transcendental.

The usual way is to show that it's a Liouville number, which will conclude that it's transcendental.

However, I know how to do it to numbers in the form of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n!}}$ for example, and here I am struggling to bring the number $[2;2^{1!}, 2^{2!}, 2^{3!}, \cdots]$ to a form of a sum.

So, I simply need help in turning it to a form of a sum.

Comment: It suffices to show that if [$$\limsup\frac{(\ln n!+\ln\ln2)\sqrt{\ln n}}n=\infty$$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24958/showing-e-is-transcendental-using-its-continued-fraction-expansion) then the continued fraction is transcendental.